# How to check the group id of a user CakePHP

Tags: php, html, css, cakephp

I'm looking at checking the Group id of a user then comparing it to the user's Group name. The code I have so far is in the login function (which is still work in progress):

```
$this->User->data = $this->data;

    //find the user based on the data from the login form
    $results = $this->User->findByemail ($this->data['User']['email']);
    $this->User->id = $results['User']['id'];

    $name = 'admin';

    $admin['Group']['name'] = $this->User->Group->find('list', array('conditions' => array('Group.name' => $name)));

        $str1 = $admin;
        $str2 = 'admin';

        if (strcmp($admin, 'admin'))
        {
            debug ('Yes, admin matches'); die();
        }
```

So far I have the find for the group id but I'm struggling to compare the name with the string 'admin'. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your `$admin` seems to be an array, while `strcmp()` takes two strings as an argument. The result of this comparison is probably not what you might expect it to be.

Second, `find('list')` [will return](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/retrieving-your-data.html) the field specified by `$displayField` which [can be defined](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#model-displayfield) for each model. You either need to specify the displayField or the fields in your `find()`-call.

Answer (score 0):

First You need to add relation of Group with User in User Model like as :

```
public $belongsTo = array(
    'Group'
);
```

and add a group_id in user table Than you will get the role name in controller like as :

```
$results = $this->User->findByemail ($this->data['User']['email']);
$group = $results['Group']['name'];
```

After that you match the string.